# Porting generated but static-from-now-on data to another application

Tags: c#, file

I programmed a simple app in C# which gathers data from various sources and creates a `clean-final-ready-for-use-data`. It's an array of a custom class which contains only primitive types (`int`, `string`, ...)

Now, I want to use this data in another C# app. what is the best way (quick and clean) to export  the data there? `BinaryFormatter`, `XML`, `hand-made-text-file` or something else?

another Q: can I store my data in a managed `DLL` by any chance?

Comment: Define "clean" - code? Output? What will be using the data?

Comment: by clean I mean not dirty and maybe reusable! I think a hand made file is quite dirty.

Comment: as I said, another C# app will use the data. (read only)

Comment: Not dirty is just the opposite of clean - it doesn't explain what you think it means (and hand coded can be very clean). What do you mean?

Comment: you might be more OK with reusable then. I want to change little code, if I had to report the data (in case of data change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just serialize your objects using the built-in .NET object serialization. See:

[Object Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)

As you are simply loading them into another .NET application, the file format doesn't really matter to much. I'd just go with an XML serializer. Yes, you can embed this data into a DLL as a resource.

Comment: thanks :)
can you provide me a link of built-in serializers please?